# How to link jemalloc shared library using cmake

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, cmake, linker, jemalloc

I'm trying to link the jemalloc library into my application at build time using it as a generic implementation. According to https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Getting-Started the linking flags to use are:

```
-L`jemalloc-config --libdir` -Wl,-rpath,`jemalloc-config --libdir` -ljemalloc `jemalloc-config --libs`
```

So I did the following **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project(widget)
include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(widget ${SOURCES})
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L`jemalloc-config --libdir` -Wl,-rpath,`jemalloc-config --libdir` -ljemalloc `jemalloc-config --libs`")
```

But when I do `make` I get the following **errors**:

```
Linking CXX executable widget
c++: error: `jemalloc-config: No such file or directory
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--libdir`’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--libdir`’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--libs`’
make[2]: *** [widget] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/widget.dir/all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 6):

For future generations, as this still comes up as one of the first links on Google.

Jemalloc comes with pkg-config setup, which can be used like this:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules (JEMALLOC jemalloc)

pkg_search_module(JEMALLOC REQUIRED jemalloc)
include_directories(${JEMALLOC_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(your_target_name ${JEMALLOC_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

[execute_process()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process) command is your friend. Use it to run `jemalloc-config` executable and then put its output into CMake variables.

Answer (score 0):

1. find you root_dir of jemalloc. Mine is  `/Users/lion/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.2.1_1/lib/`
   (I install `jemalloc` by `brew` on macOS)
2. link (soft link) all its lib to your local lib `ln -s /Users/lion/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.2.1_1/lib/* /usr/local/lib`

Then it works!